# ¿como puedo sustituir una fecha usando compile_obj.subn?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, compilar

Hago esto

```
  for fich in ficheros:
            coincidencias = re.search(patron, fich)             
            #print(coincidencias)
            if coincidencias:
                print("coincide ----------------------->"+fich)
```

Resultado

```
CRC_recup_backup_2018_11_20_004003_1817970.bak
CRC_recup_backup_2018_11_21_004001_6027986.bak
CRC_recup_backup_2018_11_22_004001_7717997.bak
CRC_Test_backup_2018_11_16_004002_9068137.bak
coincide ----------------------->CRC_Test_backup_2018_11_17_004001_5428005.bak
coincide ----------------------->CRC_Test_backup_2018_11_18_004001_6838108.bak
coincide ----------------------->CRC_Test_backup_2018_11_19_004000_9968014.bak
```

Necesito sustituir la fecha de esos ficheros por la fecha de hoy `newstr = compile_obj.subn('2018_11_22', 0)` lo que no se es si dentro del parentesis es lo que quiero sustuir o poner el valor de lo que quiero sustituir

Comment: Es decir, pongamos que tienes uno o varios ficheros con este nombre: `Ficherillo_2011_11_11_121212_1234567.bak` y querrías cambiar ese string para que utilice la fecha actual así: `Ficherillo_2018_11_23_140505_1234567.bak`. Es correcto?

Comment: si julio es justo eso, no sabia si hacerlo con compile_obj.subn(' ', ) o hacer una función, ¿Que me recomiendas?

Comment: ¿Me podrías indicar como sería para poder conseguirlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba con lo siguiente (en el ejemplo, remplazo las fechas por 2020_08_09)

Para ello utilizo la expresión regular `(?<=_)[12]\d{3}_[01]\d_[0123]\d(?=_)`

El código podría ser lo siguiente:

```
import re

regex = r"(?<=_)[12]\d{3}_[01]\d_[0123]\d(?=_)"

test_str = ("CRC_recup_backup_2018_11_20_004003_1817970.bak\n"
    "CRC_recup_backup_2018_11_21_004001_6027986.bak\n"
    "CRC_recup_backup_2018_11_22_004001_7717997.bak\n"
    "CRC_Test_backup_2018_11_16_004002_9068137.bak")

subst = "2020_08_09"

result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)
```

[Demo del código](https://ideone.com/WNKUD3)

[Demo de la expresión regular](https://regex101.com/r/JsNnW1/4/)

Comment: Tengo una duda,,, yo solo necesitaría cambiar la fecha o fechas Ejemplo:(2018_11_21). En este Ejemplo que me pones tb modificas los números de después de la fecha verdad 004001_6027986?

Comment: otra duda es, me da error la variable multiline porque no la conoce

Comment: Sí, pensaba que formaba parte de la fecha (horas, minutos, segunos + nanosegundos). Ahora lo modifico para que funcione según tu caso. Respecto al re.MULTILINE, puedes ignorarlo, realmente no es necesario si vas línea a línea

Comment: vale gracias, no te molestes he hecho las modificaciones y omitiendo el error de multiline, funciona a la perfección

Comment: Lo acabo de cambiar para remplazar solo la fecha (año, mes y día). Si te sirvió, recuerda a aceptar la respuesta. Gracias :)

Comment: Apartir de aqui ya me cambia el nombre a los ficheros y todo correcto. ¿Habría alguna manera de poder incrustar dentro del regex el valor de subst?regex = r"(?<=_)[12]\d{3}_[01]\d_[0123]\d_"               subst = "2018_11_26_"

Comment: Una cosa es la expresión regular de búsqueda y otra cosa es la sustitución. En el ejemplo puedes ver como en la misma instrucción `re.sub` tienes ambas cosas. El primer parámetro es la expresión regular y el segundo es la sustitución, que está en una variable. Pero si quisieras podrías ponerlo directamente: `result = re.sub(regex, subst, "2020_08_09", 0, re.MULTILINE)`